# multiple radio box selected generate one value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have been trying to generate value to selection all I have been able to get the single value of the single selection.

I want to know how can I combine two selections and generate one value example:

If the person has selected **private and half-day** I want the value to be a private half-day

if the person has selected **private and full-day** I want the value to be private full-day

If the person has selected **shared and half-day** I want the value to be a shared half-day

if the person has selected **shared and full-day** I want the value to be shared full-day

```js
(function() {
    var stripe = Stripe('pktest');
    var location = document.querySelector('#location');
    
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    
  
    btn.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
      var occupancy = $('input:radio[name=occupancy]:checked').val();
      var atv = $('input:radio[name=atv]:checked').val();
      e.preventDefault();
      fetch('/checkout_sessions', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          occupancy: occupancy,
          atv: atv,
          location: location.value,
        }),
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((session) => {
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
    });
  })();
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; width: 100%">
  <input type="radio" name="occupancy" id="private" value="private" checked="checked">
  <label for="private">Private</label>
  <input type="radio" name="occupancy" id="shared" value="shared">
  <label for="shared">Shared</label>
</div>
<div style="display: flex; width:100%">
  <input type="radio" name="atv" id="full-day" value="Full-Day" checked="checked">
  <label for="full-day">Full Day</label>
  <input type="radio" name="atv" id="half-day" value="Half-Day">
  <label for="half-day">Half Day</label>
</div>
<div class="location"><input id="location" type="text" placeholder="location" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'location'"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Can't you concatenate your `occupancy` and `atv` variables into a new unique variable before using `fetch()`?
2. As a side note, you should avoid using `var` so widely in your code. `let` and `const` are by far better ways of managing your variables without polluting the global scope.

Comment: need one example please like if I get the value from ATV and occupancy and then use if statement to combine them and generate a new value with a new variable then will I be able to use that new variable to send it to JSON.stringfly

Comment: You don't need if statement as I can tell. `occupancy` and `atv` are two string variables so you can always concatenate them (with **+** operator or with a _template literal_ ) in a new variable: `const yourNewVariable = occupancy + " " + atv;` So the new variable will always be one among "private Half-Day", "private Full-Day", "shared Half-Day", "shared Full-Day"

Comment: thanks, sometimes small code need some limelight to fix it you were the sunshine